# How to display all values get by jquery .each() and display in single alert box?

Tags: jquery

I would like to display a alert message based on some validation on checked items. Here is what I tried so far:

```
var result = [];
jQuery('#ct1').on("click", function(event){
    jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {        
        qtyval = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-    detail').find('input[name="qty"]').val();                                             
        var qtyval1 = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-    detail').find('.qtyonhand').text();
        var ndcCode = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-    detail').find('.ndc').text(); 
        var itemName = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-    detail').find('.itemname').text(); 
        var qtyu= parseFloat(qtyval1);
        var strrsult = result.push(qtyval1);

        if (qtyval > qtyu) {
            var strrsult = result.toString(); 
            alert(strrsult);
        }
    });
});
```

and the value of available quantity which i am getting is not displaying in single alert box.
As i have just started learning jQuery i am not getting how to display alert message in this format

```
Alert message format should be like this
```

"For the following items, the ordered quantity exceeds the current available quantity.  Please adjust the quantity and retry.

```
NDCCODE1   Item Name1  -  Available Qty:  qty1
NDCCODE2   Item Name2  -  Available Qty:  qty2
```

Comment: Did you check my answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39787257/6608101 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it on a variable like this

```
jQuery('#ct1').on("click", function(event){
var txt = "";
var result = [];
jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {        
    qtyval = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-    detail').find('input[name="qty"]').val();                                             
    var qtyval1 = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-    detail').find('.qtyonhand').text();
    var ndcCode = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-    detail').find('.ndc').text(); 
    var itemName = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-    detail').find('.itemname').text(); 
    var qtyu= parseFloat(qtyval1);
    var strrsult = result.push(qtyval1);

    if (qtyval > qtyu) {
        var strrsult = result.toString(); 
        txt += strrsult + "\\n";
    }
});
alert(txt);
});
```

\n is for make a line break if dosn't work try with br

Comment: In alert im getting blank value

Comment: pull up alert one line, and txt one down, now i edit the code and try it, and delete txt definition inside if.. sorry

Comment: Im getting alert one time but when im selecting more than 1 checkbox first value is getting repeat. Like 0,0,13 if i select two checkbox. why is it so?

Comment: ok, i think it's because we are using array result, what about if we don't use it for add text to string with var qutyval1 or using one string to write the format with variables and after add to variable txt? Do you understand me?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
var vl = '';
jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) { 
 vl += yourvalue+',';
});
alert(vl);
```

Your all value will show in alert by comma separated

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()`

```
var selected = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
      return `yourvalue`; //$(this).val();
}).get().join(",");
alert(selected);
```